# Unit Testing abstract classes and or interfaces

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, interface

I'm trying to start using Unit Testing on my current project in Visual Studio 2010. My class structure, however, contains a number of interface and abstract class inheritance relationships.

If two classes are derived from the same abstract class, or interface I'd like to be able to share the testing code between them. I'm not sure how to do this exactly. I'm thinking I create a test class for each interface I want to test, but I'm not sure the correct way to feed my concrete classes into the applicable unit tests.

---

**Update**

OK here's an example. Say I have an interface IEmployee , which is implemented by an abstract class Employee, which is then inherited by the two concrete classes Worker and Employee. (Code show below)

Now say I want to create tests that apply to all IEmployees or Employees. Or alternatively create specific tests for specific types of Employees. For example I may want to assert that setting IEmployee.Number to a number less then zero for any implementation of IEmployee throws an exception. I'd prefer to write the tests from the perspective of any IEmployee and then be able to use the tests on any implementation of IEmployee.

Here's another example. I may also want to assert that setting the vacation time for any employee to a value less then zero throws and error. Yet I may also want to have different tests that apply to a specific concrete version of Employee. Say I want to test that Worker throws an exception if they are provided more then 14 days vacation, but a manager can be provided up to 36.

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    int Number {get; set;}
}


public abstract class Employee:IEmploee
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    int Number {get;set;}
    public abstract int VacationTime(get; set;)
}


public abstract class Worker:IEmployee
{
    private int v;

    private int vTime;
    public abstract int VacationTime
    {
       get
       {
         return VTime;
       }
       set
      { 
         if(value>36) throw new ArgumentException("Exceeded allowed vaction");
         if(value<0)throw new ArgumentException("Vacation time must be >0");
         vTime= value;
       }
    }


    public void DoSomWork()
    {
      //Work
    }
}


public abstract class Manager:IEmployee
{
    public abstract int VacationTime
    {
       get
       {
         return VTime;
       }
       set
      { 
         if(value>14) throw new ArgumentException("Exceeded allowed vaction");
         if(value<0)throw new ArgumentException("Vacation time must be >0");
         vTime= value;
       }
    }

  public void DoSomeManaging()
  {
      //manage
  }

}
```

So I guess what I'm looking for is a work flow that will allow me to nest unit tests. So for example when I test the Manager class I want to first test that it passes the Employee and IEmployee tests, and then test specific members such as `DoSomeManaging()`.

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to do. You talk about unit testing interfaces but this doesn't make sense. What exactly are you trying to test? Could you provide a short and concise example of your object hierarchy and point out what do you want to test in this hierarchy?

Comment: I don't want to unit test the interface it self, but I want to be able to group all all the tests that apply to an interface so I can easily apply all those tests to any class which implements the interface. See the example I added to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess I know what you mean. I had the same issue.

My solution was to create a hierarchy also for testing. I'll use the same example you show.

First, have an abstract test class for the base IEmployee.

It has two main things:
i. All the test methods you want.
ii. An abstract method that returns the desired instance of the IEmployee.

```
[TestClass()]
public abstract class IEmployeeTests
{
    protected abstract GetIEmployeeInstance();

    [TestMethod()]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
    IEmployee target = GetIEmployeeInstance();
    // do your IEmployee test here
    }

}
```

Second, you have a test class for each implementation of IEmployee, implementing the abstract method and providing appropriate instances of IEmployee.

```
[TestClass()]
public class WorkerTests : IEmployeeTests
{

    protected override GetIEmployeeInstance()
    {
        return new Worker();
    }

}

[TestClass()]
public class ManagerTests : IEmployeeTests
{

    protected override GetIEmployeeInstance()
    {
        return new Manager();
    }

}
```

You can see everything works as expected and VS gives you the expected test methods for each WorkerTests and ManagerTests classes in the TestView window. 
You can run them and have the test results for each implementation of the IEmployee interface, having to create the tests only in the base IEmployeeTests class.

You can always add specific test for the derived WorkerTests and ManagerTests classes.

The question would be now, what about classes that implement multiple interfaces, let's say EmployedProgrammer?

```
public EmployedProgrammer : IEmployee, IProgrammer
{
}
```

We don't have multiple inheritance in C#, so this is not an option:

```
[TestClass()]
public EmployedProgrammerIEmployeeTests : IEmployeeTests, IProgrammerTests
{
     // this doesn't compile as IEmployeeTests, IProgrammerTests are classes, not interfaces
}
```

For this scenario, a solution is to have the following test classes:

```
[TestClass()]
public EmployedProgrammerIEmployeeTests : IEmployeeTests
{
    protected override GetIEmployeeInstance()
    {
        return new EmployedProgrammer();
    }
}

[TestClass()]
public EmployedProgrammerIProgrammerTests : IProgrammerTests
{
    protected override GetIProgrammerInstance()
    {
        return new EmployedProgrammer();
    }
}
```

with

```
[TestClass()]
public abstract class IProgrammerTests
{
    protected abstract GetIProgrammerInstance();

    [TestMethod()]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IProgrammer target = GetIProgrammerInstance();
        // do your IProgrammerTest test here
    }

}
```

I'm using this with good results. 
Hope it helps.

Regards,
Jose

Comment: This is called a "contract test". When working in a TDD way, you should have extracted the abstract test class around the time you have extracted the Employee class in your code during refactoring step.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want to do is create unit tests for methods in abstract classes.

I'm not sure it makes sense to want to test a protected method on an abstract class, but if you insist simply extend the class in a class used exclusively for unittesting. That way you can expose the protected methods on the abstract class you want to test through public methods on the extending class that simply call through to the method on the abstract class.

If you have methods in abstract classes that you want unittested, I suggest refactoring them into separate classes and simply expose them as public methods and put those under test. Try looking at your inheritance tree from a 'test-first' perspective and I'm pretty sure you'll come up with that solution (or a similar one) as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have described "composite unit testing" which is not supported by Visual Studio 2010 unit tests. Such things can be done in MbUnit according to this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/jdhcompositeunittesting.aspx). It is possible to create [abstract tests](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AbstractTest) in Visual Studio 2010 which is probably not exactly what you want. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182516%28VS.90%29.aspx) is description how to implement abstract tests in VS (Inheritance Example section).

Answer (score 0):

Use microsoft moles for better testing. so you can mock the abstract base class / static methods etc easily. Please refer the following post for more info

[detouring-abstract-base-classes-using-moles](http://ultimatetutorial.com/post/detouring-abstract-base-classes-using-moles)

```
BenzCar benzCar = new BenzCar();    
new MCar(benzCar)
    {
            Drive= () => "Testing"
    }.InstanceBehavior = MoleBehaviors.Fallthrough;

var hello = child.Drive();

Assert.AreEqual("Benz Car driving. Testing", hello);
```

Answer (score 0):

The desire to run the same test against multiple classes usually means you have an opportunity to extract the behavior you want to test into a single class (whether it's the base class or an entirely new class you compose into your existing classes).

Consider your example: instead of implementing vacation limits in `Worker` and `Manager`, add a new member variable to `Employee`, 'MaximumVacationDays', implement the limit in the employee class' setter, and check the limit there:

```
abstract class Employee {
    private int maximumVacationDays;
    protected Employee(int maximumVacationDays) {
        this.maximumVacationDays = maximumVacationDays
    }
    public int VacationDays {
        set { 
            if (value > maximumVacationDays)
                throw new ArgumentException("Exceeded maximum vacation");
            }
    }
}

class Worker: Employee {
    public Worker(): Employee(14) {}
}

class Manager: Employee {
    public Manager(): Employee(36) {}
}
```

Now you have only one method to test and less code to maintain.